# how to find out client ip address and client process id which connected server's specify socket

Tags: linux

for example:

our linux license server deomon is on "5280@192.168.22.1".

we have many client linux to connect 5280 on 192.168.22.1.

I want to find out which client process id connect "5280@192.168.22.1", and I also need to know the client ip address.

how to ?

Thanks!

all machine is "linux".  server is also "linux"

Comment: ... In the program? From the command line? Where?

Answer (score 2):

If the client is "Linux", on the client:

```
#netstat -ant -p | grep "192.268.22.1:5280"
```

You would find the process id/name which connect to the server on port 5280.

On the server:

```
#netstat -ant -p | grep "192.268.22.1:5280"
```

You would find the client ip which connect to the server on port 5280.

BTW, you can not find the client process id/name on the server.

Comment: hi ageek2remember, the command result is show all connections PID/Program name "-". Do you have any suggestions ?